# Perform Terminal Commands Without Opening the Terminal - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Is there anyway, within Linux, to open a terminal or perform a terminal command (such as executing a script) without actually opening the terminal window. What i'd like to do is be able to execute a script from the terminal without the user knowing.

Alternatively is there a shortcut or method to make the terminal window transparent. I know I could create a start up process to run the command, but this would involve opening the terminal window and alerting the user.

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to run a script periodically, save the script and run it as a cronjob. Executing a cronjob  do not require a terminal to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when you need start script.

- repeated tasks: write script and use Cron mentioned by @ThreadedLemon ([nice set of examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/))
- on startup: write script, use `chmod +x` on script and use init.d ([example on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup))
- on user logon: write script and use ~/.profile (or similar name depends on distro) ([info on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97137/how-do-you-run-a-script-on-login-in-nix))